# Can I Use Printer Paper for Labels

Tags: bottles, labels

I plan to do enough brewing this summer to have more than one brew available for drinking. Therefore, I want to label my bottles.

I know about using milk for attaching labels, but I was wondering if anyone has used regular printer paper for labels? Or is it too thick to attach properly?

Comment: Not an answer as it does not address your question, but have you considered just taking a sharpie and putting a code on the top of the bottle caps? I did this while I still bottled, and while I only had 2 codes so they were easy to remember, a reference sheet wouldn't be that hard either.

Answer (score 3):

I have used normal printer paper with no problems at all, glued with Prit Stick as it sticks a bit more than milk.

I did have one batch for which a friend with a letterpress printer had printed some labels on quite thick paper, almost thin card, and even that was still flexible enough to be stuck on with Prit Stick.

Now I use normal Avery inkjet labels, 6 per sheet size, and they're fine.  Go on easily, though you can't straighten them once they're stuck so you need to be careful if you don't want them to be crooked, but I prefer that to faffing about with glue.  They also come off quite easily after a day or so soaking in water.

I only normally label 12 from a batch and mark the caps for the rest, as otherwise it's a lot of labels and ink for each brew!

Answer (score 1):

Paper labels with milk will work fine as long as they aren't going in a cooler full of ice water.  If their going in a fridge you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

I have also used printer paper with standard ink and agree with brewchez... I wouldnt put them in a lot of moister.